# Table split on pages (BIP)

Tags: xml, oracle, rtf, bi-publisher

I need help for a problem with RTF and BI Publisher (BIP).

I have a group by a field, let's say, `journal_type`. Each `journal_type` has a long table which goes ahead many pages and also has 12 columns for the 12 months of year. I need to show at each bottom of page a row with partial sums for each month column.

As far as I did is:

1. After grouping defining some variables:

   ```
   <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’, 0)?>
   <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘lines_page’, 16)?>
   <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘tot_lines’, count(.//A.U_VATX))?>
   ```
2. Inside the cell of first column:

   ```
   <?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’,xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘counter’)+1)?>
   <?if@inlines:xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’counter’) != xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’tot_lines’)?>
   <?if@inlines:position() mod xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘lines_page’) = xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,’lines_page’)-1?><?call:footer?><?end if?>
   <?if@inlines:position() mod xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘lines_page’) = 0?><?call:breaking?><?end if?><?end if?>
   ```
3. After table, defining the templates:

   ```
   <?template:footer?>
   table cell with data
   <?end template?>
   <?call-template:footer?>
   <?template:breaking?> 
     table cell empty
     <?split-by-page-break:?> 
     <?end template?>
   ```
4. End

It's working but the last row of table it is overlapped on the last column, when showing the partially sum and this cell is under the cell providing from the last column of table.

Comment: Not really. I splitted the problem into 2 problems.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your problem? I'm having trouble understanding what it is.